# Order Rake Tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, task

I've read a lot but i'm confused.

I'm trying to order the execution of my Rake tasks but haven't any luck yet. The Task looks like this:

```
task :populate do

  # 1st in Order
  Rake::Task['import0'].invoke
  Rake::Task['import00'].invoke

  # 2nd in Order
  Rake::Task['import000'].invoke
  Rake::Task['import0000'].invoke

  # 3rd in Order
  Rake::Task['import000000'].invoke

  # 4th in Order
  Rake::Task['import1'].invoke
  Rake::Task['import2'].invoke
  Rake::Task['import3'].invoke

  # 5th in Order
  Rake::Task['importA'].invoke
  Rake::Task['importB'].invoke
  Rake::Task['importC'].invoke

end
```

How can i order the execution of invokes being called. Do i have to call it from the Initial Tasks itself?

Comment: How many tasks are there for each set?

Comment: Every call, invokes only 1 Task..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the order when they are called.

With a maximum of 3 in each set, I would do it this way:

```
TASKS = [ :import0, :import00, :import000, :import0000, :import000000,
          :import1, :import2,  :import3,
          :importA, :importB,  :importC ]

TASKS.each do |t|
  Rake::Task[t.to_s].invoke
end
```

Comment: Hey Seven, sorry but i misunderstood your comment, each invoke calls ONE task.. basically `Rake::Task['import1'].invoke` invokes the `:import1 Task`. Still the same ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to invoke the tasks above, this is a good way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you save the task names as symbols first and then convert them back to strings? Might as well make them strings in the first place.

Comment: When possible, I prefer to use symbols instead of strings. It cleaner. Also, in this case I don't think you need to convert to string, but I didn't test it so I wasn't sure.